# Email template showing blank values. Shows text but field values are blank

Tags: salesforce, processbuilder, email-templates

I have an email template of text type which has around 15 field values of parent object. The process builder and email alert is written on child object so whenever child object is created I am sending emails. Using available merge fields I am sending values as
{!Parentobj.fieldname}

The email is firing as per criteria but values of fields are not displayed. Is there any way to fix this?
I cannot use visualforce templates or create 15 formula fields on child.

Also when I click send test and very merge fields and see the template in preview mode the values are populating correctly.
Please suggest if u know any workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If it works in preview for sysadmin but not end users it sounds like permissions issue.

Check if the user that's running the process has Profile permissions to see the parent object and these 15 fields on the parent.

If that's good - check if this user has sharing permission to see this particular parent (at least readonly access). If you aren't sure - you could switch to Classic UI and add [Sharing] button to parent's page layout and clicking it will give you detailed info who can see it & why.

Some more obscure things - is the parent object marked "in development"? Are you sure the email runs in right time? If you start with parent blank and then something updates the lookup field - maybe the email gets queued too early and you'd need to add `Parent__c != null` to criteria...